# How i can use Navigation Controller only certain View Controllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, segue

I try create registration screen and after -> Home Page with side menu. I create model layout with two screenshots. I can't understand why my registration screen have button back and how i can implement navigation controller only after i go in Home Page?

this is first way - if i use segue for Home Page

[image: this is first way - if i use segue for Home Page]

and second way - if i use segue for Navigation Controller

[image: and second way - if i use segue for Navigation Controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: solution]

I guess this is what you want. You can translation from `HomeVC` to `LoginVC` with kind `Modal`

Comment: Yes. This is definitely what I want. Thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome, can you give me a vote if you like to, thank you